# ResultSetMetaData getTableName return empty String

Tags: java

I am trying to get TableName from ResultSetMetaData by following code

```
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"releaseUN", "releasepw");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String qry = "";
        qry = "  SELECT  *  FROM MyTable ";
        
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(qry);
        ResultSetMetaData md = rset.getMetaData();
        int col = md.getColumnCount();
        
         for (int i = 1; i <= col; i++) {
            System.out.println("getTableName "+ md.getTableName(i));
     
         }
```

But it returns Empty String
I used ojdbc14.jar to connect to Oracle Database by jdbc connectivity

Actually i want Table Name for each selected column in the given query.

Comment: Can you show us a little bit more from your code? Connection query and so on?

Comment: Are you sure that `String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";` is correct! I think `orcl` should be replaced by XE.

Comment: yes shekhar, orcl is correct ,when i use xe its give me error
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection

Comment: are you sure your connection is being established??try throwing the exception by surrounding it with try catch

Comment: Yes Sir connection is getting established, i am able to print column data by this code
while (rset.next()) {

 System.out.println(rset.getString(1));
   }

Comment: but your code is working perfectly fine for me. It will display you the table name as many times as there are columns in your table

Comment: Yes Sir, some are able to get by the same code and some developers cant, they says " getTableName is not implemented by the driver."

Comment: surround it with try catch i think you will get some exception

Comment: @M.Sharma, No exception sir, code runs fine but return empty string by that method

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of ResultSetMetaData says it returns blank if not applicable.

```
String getTableName(int column)
                    throws SQLException 
Gets the designated column's table name.
 Parameters:column - the first column is 1, 
the second is 2, ... 
Returns:table name or "" if not applicable 
Throws: SQLException - if a database access error occurs
```

Comment: exactly Jens, its retuning blank (empty string) for me, some guys are able to get tableName from same method, but for my side it doesnt work,
Any other solution Jens?

Comment: @Kamal The documentation says nothing about what "not applicable" means. It's possible that you need special permissions or it depends on the DBMS.

Comment: @Kamal or look [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/934007?tstart=0) "Unfortunately, getTableName is not implemented by the driver. If you think about it, it is not very straightforward to implement considering the possible complexity of an sql query. "

Comment: I gone through link you gave, and they said no implementation for  that method,Anyways appreciate your help Jens